# High frequency noise from headphones when connected to cellphone

Tags: headphones

I am having a problem with my phone... when i connect headphones(any headphones) to the 3,5mm jack and play audio, there is a tiny high frequency noise in the background. However, this is only present when there is sound playing.. if i stop playing sound the high frequency noise stops after a few secconds... I am thinking that it must be the processor of the phone generating the noise, and the sound card is not filtering it out...

The cellphone is an LG Optimus 4X HD

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to Force Stop MediaServer might help if the problem exists within videos too.